# not working-roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: c, equation

I can't even take `b` and `c` from the keyboard. it stops after enter `a` value and gives the result always like 0.0000.  What's wrong with this code ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    float a,b,c,d;
    float x1,x2;

    printf("enter a,b,c\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    d = b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (d<0) {
        printf ("no real roots");
    }
    else 
    {
        x1= (-b + sqrt (d)) / 2*a;
        x2= (-b - sqrt (d)) / 2*a;

        printf ("the roots are\n");
        printf ("x1=%f x2=%f",x1,x2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you entering in the console? And how can it give a result if it stops during user input?

Comment: looks just fine in here (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler). What are **exactly** your inputs and outputs ?

Comment: Include <stdio.h> instead of  <iostream> and compile with all warning enabled. But otherwise your code looks fine.

Comment: Provide a description of what you are actually entering from the keyboard - that is relevant.     Check the return value from `scanf()` since that is how it reports errors.    You may get information of use if you print the values read immediately after reading them.   `<iostream>` is a C++ header, not C - use `<stdio.h>`.    Also, your formula for calculating the roots is wrong - `2*a` needs to be bracketed.

Comment: Are you using `3,45` to indicate 3 and 45 hundredths perhaps?  If so, you need to `#include <locale.h>` at the top of the file and use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` before your `printf()` statement.  If that isn't your problem, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and provide the extra information — most notably exactly what you're typing.  It's a good idea, especially when having problems, to print the inputs as soon as you've got them.  It's also always a good idea to check that `scanf()` returns the correct value (3 in this case).  If not, there's a problem during the input.